# RealmSwiftで複数のclassを一つのListで保存したい。

Tags: swift, ios, xcode, realm, swift4

現在、ユーザーの複数のSNSアカウントを管理するアプリを制作しています。
その中で、登録された複数のSNSアカウントの情報からユーザーが選択したアカウントだけを一つのListにまとめたいのですが、SNSアカウントの情報のをclassで定義しておりListを利用できません。何か良い解決方法があれば教えてください。よろしくお願いします。

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Twitter: Object {
    @objc dynamic var userID = ""
    @objc dynamic var screenName = ""
    @objc dynamic var userName = ""
    @objc dynamic var imageURL = ""
}

class Facebook: Object {
    @objc dynamic var userName = ""
    @objc dynamic var imageURL = ""
}

class UserProfile: Object {
    //このclass内で下のlistにTwitterクラスやFacebookクラスのインスタンスを追加したい
    //@objc dynamic var list
}
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/117049

Answer (score 1, accepted):

できません。RealmおよびSwiftの制限によりListに格納できるのはそれぞれ１つの型のみです。共通に扱いたい場合は、TwitterクラスとFacebookクラスの共通のプロパティを持つスーパークラスのようなものを定義するか、あきらめてListとListをそれぞれ別の関連として持つかのどちらかになります。

Comment: そうですよね。回答いただきありがとうございます。